# "A man who gave it up for 700 days.." vs "A man who has given it up for 700 days..."

Tags: prepositions, present-perfect, past-simple, adverbial-phrases

> 1. A man who gave it up **for** 700 days says it gave him superpowers.

Is the tense used in this sentence right? So far I know prefect tense is used with " for/ since" when we indicate time.If I say-

> 2. A man who has given it up  **for** 700 days says it gives him superpowers.

Which one is right?

Answer (score 3):

Both of them are grammatically correct, but they mean different things.  You can certainly use *for* with the simple past: it just means "over this span of time", and its use doesn't force any particular tense.  *Since* is different, because it means "between the named time and now".

The difference is simply the one between the simple past and the present perfect:

> He **gave** it up for 700 days

means that at some point in the past, he stopped doing it for 700 days, but the action is now over and completed.

> He **has given** it up for 700 days

means that as of right now, he has not done it for the *last* 700 days, and still isn't doing it.

References:
 - [Present Perfect and Past Simple](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-perfect-or-past-simple.html)
 - [How To Teach Past Simple VS Present Perfect](http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/410/grammar/ppvpast.htm)

Comment: I have seen your reference. My question is that what's the differences between-1.I lived in Victoria for five years  2.I had lived Victoria for 5 years.

Comment: @AbdulKaiumTanvir - Now you're talking about the difference between the past simple and the past perfect.  Past simple: at some time in the past, this thing happened.  Past perfect: at some time in the past, this thing *had already happened* **earlier than that**.